# C program not reading arguments correctly

Tags: c

I'm writing a program and I want to accept commandline arguments but when I pass any args, it acts as if start is always called. My code is below. Any help is appreciated.

```
//compile to iservices
// Ilkotech Services - C Core
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc < 2) {
        printf("Usage: %s start|shutdown|reload\n",argv[0]);
    }
    else {
        if (strcmp(argv[1],"start") != 0) {
            services_start();
        }
        else if (strcmp(argv[1],"shutdown") != 0) {
            services_shutdown();
        }
        else if (strcmp(argv[1],"reload") != 0) {
            services_reload();
        }
        else {
            printf("%s is not a valid argument\n",argv[1]);
            printf("Usage: %s start|shutdown|reload\n",argv[0]);
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
int services_start() {
    printf("Started.\n");
    return 0;
}
int services_shutdown() {
    printf("Shutting down!\n");
    return 0;
}
int services_reload() {
    printf("Reloading services configuration.\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`strcmp` returns 0 if the both strings are equals.

> **C11 (n1570), § 7.24.4.2 The `strcmp` function**
>   The `strcmp` function returns an integer greater than, equal to, or less than zero,
>   accordingly as the string pointed to by `s1` is greater than, equal to, or less than the string pointed to by `s2`.

Some programmers used to call the following macro:

```
#include <string.h>
#define cmp_strings(a, b) (strcmp(a, b) == 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [the online C++ reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcmp/), strcmp() returns zero if the strings are equal.  That being the case, your code would be saying, essentially, if the first argument is NOT "start", run services_start().